# i have a problem after upgrading to 22.04 with the libgl1-mesa-dri

Tags: apt, dpkg

this is the output i get when i try to do anything apt related:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2~git2204220600.5e8433~oibaf~j is installed
                   Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2~git2204220600.5e8433~oibaf~j is installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Recommends: libgl1-amber-dri:i386 but it is not installable
                        Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 22.2~git2204220600.5e8433~oibaf~j) but 22.0.1-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

i tried the broken install thing but it didnt worked. Maybe someone can help me

Comment: The problem is likely caused by the obaif PPA you added. Remove/purge it and everything else should work.

Comment: By chance are you getting a broken pipe error on this package var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-
dri_22.1.0~rc2+git2204210644.7c75d83842e~j~
mesarc0_amd64.deb
If yes then what were you trying to install

Comment: I have following problem and I cannot peform ppa-purge because it's trying to remove most of my applications including Xorg/wayland etc.  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2) but 22.2~git2204280600.b4bbf9~oibaf~j is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you..
Try this, it might solve your problem:

https://www.nixcraft.com/t/solved-apt-and-unmet-dependencies/2453/10

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. Downgrade to libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.1-1ubuntu2).
I.E. `apt install libglapi-mesa=22.02.1-1ubuntu2`.

You then may need to remove the third party repository your current mesa version is coming from. But, be careful when doing that because when I did it I first tried to remove the unwanted repo and mesa package, ended up needing to reinstall the whole GUI, and still didn't fix the problem until also doing the package downgrade.